# RPMbuild force dependency to specific RPM in built RPM

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm facing a problem, which requires a dependency to force the install of another RPM in a specific version, when installing My newly built RPM.

Situation:
My-Old-Foo.rpm has dependency to: 3rd-Party-7.0.6 RPM
(where 7.0.6 ist part of the RPM name, NOT the version)
My-New-Foo.rpm has dependency to: 3rd-Party-7.0.7 RPM
This dependency has been put into the .spec file & the build process runs smooth so far...
BUT when installing the PRM, it checks it's dependencies to lib this.so, that.so, yaddayadda.so und finds its dependencies satisfied in:

- 3rd-Party-3.14.12-8.9.rpm
- 3rd-Party-7.0.6-2.7.rpm
- 3rd-Party-7.0.7-1.0.rpm

3rd-Party-7.0.6 is already installed, so nothig to do.

How do I force the install of 3rd-Party-7.0.7 no mater what and regardless if dependencies to libs are already satisfied, when installing My-New-Foo.rpm?

**Already tried:**
Putting dependencies in .spec file

```
BuildRequires:  3rd-Party-7.0.7
Requires:       3rd-Party-7.0.7
Requires:       some more stuff
```

Where my understanding is: "BuildRequires:" well... is requiered for the build.
While "Requires:" sets dependencies like a meta package.

Any hint appreciated
thx Sil

Comment: `3rd-Party-3.14.12-8.9` does not satisfy a dependency that requires `3rd-Party-7.0.7`. If you're seeing contrary behavior, can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates it?

Comment: (A `Provides:` line can make a package fulfill a dependency on a different version, but folks doing that responsibly only use it in backwards-facing ways)

Comment: Well to simplify the issue: its like I'm writing "requires: python3"
while the installer goes: nah! python2 already there, thats good enough for you.
So, blah-7.0.6, blah-7.0.7 is always part of the "name" not "version" or "release"
So requires >= 7.0.7 is not working here.

Comment: Right, `>=` won't work if people are putting version numbers into names -- it only matches against the version and ignores the name. The part I _don't_ believe (and building RPMs used to be my full-time job, albeit about 20 years ago) is the claim that `blah-7.0.6` fulfills a requirement for `blah-7.0.7` unless there's an explicit `Provides` or otherwise override making it so.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a [mre]. Inspect the headers of the 3rd-party RPMs if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the 3rd party RPMs are a mess; `Requires` is the proper metadata tag to use here.

Here's something to try:

```
Requires: 3rd-Party-7.0.7 = 1.0
Conflicts: 3rd-Party-7.0.6
```

Or you need to give us more information as noted in commentary.